# About domain checker for .hk and others

Tags: php, javascript, dns

I am trying to use a domain checker for .hk, .com.hk etch using the following. Its working fine for .com, .net, but not for .hk etc. pls let me know where I'm going wrong. You help would be really appreciated. 
I'm getting the following error:
Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to com.hk:43 (Connection timed out) in /home/a2314677/public_html/process.php on line 33

HTML Code:
In the head:

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var loading;
    var results;

    form = document.getElementById('form');
    loading = document.getElementById('loading');
    results = document.getElementById('results');

    $('#Submit').click( function() {

        if($('#Search').val() == "")
        {alert('please enter your domain');return false;}

        results.style.display = 'none';
        $('#results').html('');
        loading.style.display = 'inline';

        $.post('process.php?domain=' + escape($('#Search').val()),{
        }, function(response){

            results.style.display = 'block';
            $('#results').html(unescape(response)); 
            loading.style.display = 'none';
        });

        return false;
    });

});
</script>
--------------------------------------------------------

In body:

<div class="search_row">
  <div class="domains_search">
    <div class="col-1"></div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <input type="text" name="domain_search" id="Search" name="domain" class="txt_domainsearch" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <select name="domain" id="domains" class="domainoption">
        <option selected="selected">.hk</option>  
        <option>.com.hk</option>      
        <option>.net.hk</option>
        <option>.org.hk</option>
        <option>.gov.hk</option>      
        <option>.com</option>
        <option>.net</option>
        <option>.org</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="searchbtn"  id="Submit"/>
    </div>
  </div>
------------------------------------------------------------------
PHP code:
<?php
/*set_time_limit(0);*/
ob_start();

########### Extensions to be checked
$extensions = array(
    '.hk'           => array("com.hk","whois.hknic.net.hk","No Match for"), 
    '.net.hk'       => array("net.hk","whois.hknic.net.hk","No Match for"),
    '.org.hk'       => array("org.hk","whois.hknic.net.hk","No Match for"),
    '.com.hk'       => array("com.hk","whois.hknic.net.hk","No Match for"),
    '.gov.hk'       => array("gov.hk","whois.hknic.net.hk","No Match for"),
    '.com'          => array('whois.crsnic.net','No match for'),
    '.net'          => array('whois.crsnic.net','No match for'),
    '.org'          => array('whois.pir.org','NOT FOUND'),

);




if(isset($_GET['domain']))
{
    $domain = str_replace(array('www.', 'http://'), NULL, $_GET['domain']);

    if(strlen($domain) > 0)
    {
    echo '<table>
     <th>Domain Name</th>
     <th>Availability</th>';
        foreach($extensions as $extension => $who)
        {

            $sock = fsockopen($who[0], 43) or die('Error Connecting To Server:' . $server);
            fputs($sock, $domain.$extension . "\r\n");

                while( !feof($sock) )
                {
                    $buffer .= fgets($sock,128);
                }

            fclose($sock);

            if(eregi($who[1], $buffer))
            {
                echo '<tr class="available">
     <td>' . $domain. '<b>' . $extension . '</b> </td>
     <td><img src="icon_success.gif"> Available </td>';
                //echo '<h4 class="available"><span>Available</span>' . $domain. '<b>' . $extension .'</b> is Available</h4>';
            }
            else
            {
            echo '<tr  class="not_available">
     <td>' . $domain. '<b>' . $extension . '</b> </td>
     <td><img src="icon_error.gif"> Not Available </td>
     ';
                //echo '<h4 class="taken"><span>Not Available</span><a href="http://www.'. $domain .$extension .'" target="_blank">www.' . $domain . '<b>' .$extension .'</a></b> is <a href="http://whois.asiaregistry.com/displayWhois.php?zone='. $domain.$extension.'" target="_blank">Not Available</a></h4>';
            }



            ob_flush();
            flush();
            sleep(0.3);

        }echo '<br />'; 
        echo ' </tr>
     </table>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Please enter the domain name';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your $extensions array is faulty.

> ```
> $extensions = array(
>     '.hk'           => array("com.hk","whois.hknic.net.hk","No Match for"), 
>     '.net.hk'       => array("net.hk","whois.hknic.net.hk","No Match for"),
>     '.org.hk'       => array("org.hk","whois.hknic.net.hk","No Match for"),
>     '.com.hk'       => array("com.hk","whois.hknic.net.hk","No Match for"),
>     '.gov.hk'       => array("gov.hk","whois.hknic.net.hk","No Match for"),
>     '.com'          => array('whois.crsnic.net','No match for'),
>     '.net'          => array('whois.crsnic.net','No match for'),
>     '.org'          => array('whois.pir.org','NOT FOUND'),
>
> );
> ```

The first entry in the array for the com.hk entry should be `whois.hknic.net.hk` and not `com.hk` much alike the `.com` and `.net` ones. This first value is checked for the details, your values are wrong.

Comment: thanks. i changed it to this $extensions = array(
 '.hk'         => array("whois.hknic.net.hk","No Match for"), 
 '.com.hk'       => array("whois.hknic.net.hk","No Match for"),
 '.net.hk'       => array("whois.hknic.net.hk","No Match for"),
 '.org.hk'       => array("whois.hknic.net.hk","No Match for"), 
 '.gov.hk'       => array("whois.hknic.net.hk","No Match for"),
 '.com'       => array('whois.crsnic.net','No match for'),
 '.net'       => array('whois.crsnic.net','No match for'),
 '.org'       => array('whois.pir.org','NOT FOUND'),
 
); but for every entry its says 'Not Available'